# How to get selected value from alert dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm using alert dialog to show some records.those records are comming from db and display in Alertdialog.when user click on item i want to get item name to Log.this is my code.it show item as `[test]` but i want it showing as `test`

ArrayList arrayList and String [] categoryStrings initialized on top

```
    List<Video> vd=Video.findWithQuery(Video.class, "select * from Video");
            if (vd.size()>0) {

                for (Video v : vd) {

                    arrayList.add(v.getTitle());

                }

                final List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arrayList.toString());
                categoryStrings=new String[list.size()];
                categoryStrings=list.toArray(categoryStrings);

                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Editmedia.this);


                alert.setTitle("Media List");
                alert.setCancelable(false);

                final int selected = 0; // or whatever you want
                alert.setSingleChoiceItems(categoryStrings, selected, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        //onclick
                        String categoryString = categoryStrings[item];

                        Log.d("sel", " " + item+" "+categoryString);

                        edit();
                    }
                });


                alert.show();
```

log value showing 
`0 [test]` i want it as `test`

Log 
[image: Log]

Comment: how are you storing values in categoryStrings ?

Comment: Please, show this log: ` Log.d("sel", +categoryStrings);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Media List");
                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
                arrayAdapter.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, list.get(i));
                    arrayAdapter.add(list.get(i));
                }
                builder.setAdapter(arrayAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), list.get(which),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
```

Comment: Happy to hear that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should help

```
String categoryString = categoryStrings[item];

categoryString = categoryString.replaceAll("[\\p{Ps}\\p{Pe}]","");
Log.d("sel", " " +" "+categoryString);
```

[EDIT]

```
String categoryString = categoryStrings[item];

categoryString = categoryString.replace("[","");
categoryString = categoryString.replace("]","");

Log.d("sel", " " +" "+categoryString);
```

Comment: i have tried this.then it showing 'cannot resolve method replaceAll (java.lang.String,java.lang.String)'